# .NET 6 How to change default configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Upgraded a console app to .NET 6 and found that .NET 6 automatically reads in appsettings.json.

Previous code looked like this in .NET 6

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).
    ConfigureHostConfiguration(hostingContext =>
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_HOST_ENV");

        hostingContext.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
        if (env == "Development")
        {
            hostingContext.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true, true);
        }
        else
        {
            hostingContext.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        }
    });
```

Each json file was only loaded based on the env.  Now it seems that .NET 6 Host includes the appsettings.json by default.

Don't want appsettings.json to be loaded by default.

What are my options?

Comment: Are you intending to configure the host, or the app?

Answer (score 1):

The appsettings.json is chosen depending on the "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT" and "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environment variables. The latter overrides the former.

"Production" is the default value if "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT" and "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" have not been set.

Check out the [Microsoft doc on using multiple environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It's pretty detailed.

[Here is how to set it in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-environment-in-code), since I'm guessing that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

True, `.CreateDefaultBuilder` calls [`.ConfigureDefaults`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d074561fb17e778e6d7ff20a45d0700477a8cfaf/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L190) which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#default-builder-settings).

I believe you can create your `new HostBuilder()` directly, then choose which other defaults you need to implement. But it looks like there are a large number of defaults that would be complicated to re-implement.

Instead, you may be able to remove the `FileConfigurationSource` sources;

```cs
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, config) =>
{
    config.Sources.Clear();
    ...
```